# Creating decorators with access to closures

Tags: javascript, properties, closures, mutators

I have lots of little objects that all need to fulfill very similar tasks and I would like to use a decorator to modify those objects since this makes things a lot easier for me. Problem is, I also need to trigger stuff as soon as certain data on these objects is accessed while at the same time preventing outside access to the actual data. Therefore, I'm using a closure to store the private data and provide magical mutators for outside access. Finally, I'm also using a constructor for no specific reason.

This is a very reduced version of the object and the parts that give me headaches:

```
var Foo = function () {
  var hiddenState;
  return {
    set state (s) {
      // Do something that justifies using magical accessors
      state = s;
    },
    get state () {
      // Do something that justifies using magical accessors
      return state;
    }
  }
};

var o = new Foo();
o.state = 10;
```

Okay, now there are some objects that should behave a different from the rest when their mutators are used. So, I thought, I'd just overwrite the mutators and that's it:

```
// Let's suppose I have some reason to modify the magical accessors for some objects but not for others
Object.defineProperty(o, 'state', {
  get: function () {return hiddenState /*...*/},
  set: function (s) {state = s /*...*/}
});

o.state; // Ouch!
```

This doesn't work. I get a reference error because I'm trying to access `hiddenState` when it wasn't defined within the scope of the new getter/setter pair.

I suspect JS dumps the closure that was only accessible from the old mutators as soon as I pass in the new ones. Is there some way to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the closure that had access to `hiddenState` using [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor). Also, if you don't need to modifiy the getter, just don't overwrite it at all, it will persist.

```
var oldSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, 'state').set;
Object.defineProperty(o, 'state', {
  set: function (s) {
    /* do something to s */
    oldSetter(s);
  }
});
```

Comment: Wow! This was exactly what I was looking for! I was already thinking about using custom made functions to keep the old setter but this is much better.